# What subsequences does SequenceReplace consider

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, sequence

Consider `SequenceReplace[{a, b, x, x, a, c}, {a, e_} :> e]`.

**What subsequences does `SequenceReplace` consider?**

The documentation says

> SequenceReplace goes through a list, testing sequences that start at each successive element position. On each sequence, it tries in turn each of the transformation rules that were specified. If any of the rules apply, it replaces the sequence, then continues to go through the list, starting at the element position after the end of the sequence.

But it is not clear to me what "testing sequences that start at each successive element position" means. Does it:

- test all sequences of a certain length? If so, how does it determine the length?

  - For example, if the length is 2 does it look at `{a,b}` , `{b,x}`/`{x,x}` (depending on if the rule applied to `{a,b}` etc.
- test sequences of all lengths (until it finds a match), if so, what length does it start with?

Or something else?

I tried running `Trace` on the example in the first sentence, but I was not able to understand the trace

Comment: ``ReplaceList[{a, b, x, x, a, 
  c}, {Shortest[lhs___], Longest[PatternSequence[a, e_]], 
   Shortest[rhs___]} :> {1 + Length[{lhs}], 
   6 - Length[{rhs}]}, \[Infinity]]`` is used to get the subsequences that will be replaced.

Comment: in case you'd like a bit of commentary on the above comment, the presence of `Longest` means that at each sequence start position, mathemetica actually tries to match the *longest* possible pattern that starts there—and then, if any replacements occur, moves to the next surviving element. check out `SequenceReplace[{a, b, x, x, a, c}, {a, e__} :> 1]`, which is the same except it uses the "one or more expressions" pattern `e__`. If it replaced at *first* match (instead of longest), you'd expect `{1, x, x, 1}`. Instead we get `{1}`, since it matches `e__` to `Sequence[b, x, x, a, c]`.

Comment: ' SequenceReplace[{a, b, x, x, a, c}, {a, e_} :> e] ' actually deletes all the 'a', provided it is not last, because:  '{a,e_}' means: a sequence of 2 elements starting with 'a'. If you would have written '{a,e__}' , this would mean a sequence of at least 2 elements starting with 'a'.  And '{a,e___}'  a sequence starting with 'a' and at least 1 element.